# не корректно работает код на движке unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Учусь работать на Unity, по книге "Юнити в действии", и беда в том что в самой первой программе уже возникли сложности. Автор предлагает сделать "персонажа", сначало программируем его реакцию на поворот мыши по иксу(все норм), потом по игрику, код переписываю точь в точь как в книге, но вместо того что бы реагировать на движение вверх-вниз, камеру с самого запуска проекта начинает носить по всем сторонам, мб опечатка какая-нибудь(у автора, ибо полностью код копировал и вставлял, ошибка не пропала)?помогите, а то только осваиваюсь в unity вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum RotationAxes
    {
        MouseXAndY = 0,
        MouseX = 1,
        MouseY = 2
    }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityHor = 9.0f;
    public float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;
    public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    public float maximumVert = 45.0f;
    private float _rotationX = 0;
    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (body != null)
            body.freezeRotation = true;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX,maximumVert,minimumVert);
            float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityVert;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);
            float delta = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityHor;
            float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + delta;
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется вы тут напутали. Поменяйте _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX,maximumVert,minimumVert); на _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert);

Comment: @coder675 поменял, но ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: Я проверил в Unity в вашем варианте камера дергалась. После моей правки все нормально. Перепроверьте свой код еще раз. И убедитесь что в настройках скрипта выбрано Mouse Y.

Comment: @coder675 да походу с моим юнити что-то не так, ибо пришел в универ, ввел тот же код, и там все нормально работает :(

Comment: @coder675 либо я что-то не понимаю либо еще что-то, но переписал код в новый скрипт, всё заработало